# Load Sample Data in DynamoDB with AWS SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the guide from https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.02.html to learn how to load data from a json into a dynamoDB table. I have done step 2, however, when I run my code, only some movie files are successfully put into the table and some are not. For a movie that cannot be added, I receive this error:

```
Unable to add movie Meet Dave . Error JSON: {
  "message": "Requested resource not found",
  "code": "ResourceNotFoundException",
  "time": "2020-11-30T17:38:59.402Z",
  "requestId": "2D23NEFAB33E62C6PEFUFGGNM7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 28.791430704572328
}
```

Every time I delete the db and try re-run my code, different movies are successfully added and unsuccessfully added. My code is identical to the step 2 of the guide on the link above.

```
var allMovies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("movie_data.json", "utf8"));
  allMovies.forEach(function (movie) {
    var movie_params = {
      TableName: "Movies",
      Item: {
        year: movie.year,
        title: movie.title,
        info: movie.info,
      },
    };

    docClient.put(movie_params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(
          "Unable to add movie",
          movie.title,
          ". Error JSON:",
          JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
        );
      } else {
        console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.title);
      }
    });
  });
```

The movie data is a json file containing a list movies with attributes: title, year and info. Does anyone have any idea why this is not working correctly i.e. not putting all of the data successfully into the db table?.

Comment: try this   var movie_params = {
      TableName: "Movies",
      Item: {
        year: { S: movie.year},
        title: {S: movie.title},
        info: {S: movie.info},
      },
    };

Comment: I feel like I’m taking crazy pills - if we are creating these records fresh, why is it `docClient.put`...shouldn’t it be a create method, not a put?

Comment: Anyways, 400 is a bad request so, if you put a debug point before the API `put` call and step through each iteration I’d be curious what your `movie_params` object looks like each time. Make sure that each object being sent is correctly formatted, and sorted the same every time.

Comment: @Nonik this solution did not work.

Comment: @JonathanBowman the database has already been created in another function, this is just a separate function to populate the db with data from a json file

Comment: @pigsliketofly what errors are you getting?

Comment: @pigsliketofly also make sure you have correct credentials and region let cred = new AWS.Credentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
AWS.config.update({
    region: REGION,
    credentials: cred
});